# eclipse Photon SQL editor

Tags: eclipse

In former versions of `eclipse` I used to install `Data Tools Platform Extender SDK` and got an `SQL` editor.
I install the said package in eclipse Photon and don't get the possibility to select an SQL editor in the `Open with` dialog.

Where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse 4.10 I eventually installed `Data Tools Platform SQL Development Tools` and everything below like `Data Functions`and `DDL Functionality`. This brought the SQL editor.

Answer (score 0):

There use to be the following page: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sql-development-tools

It seemed to depend on DTP and it restored my SQL Editor associations as they were before updating to Photon.

The page however is now gone.

Comment: This page seems gone :(

Comment: Still definitley gone